# To which caste do people from the Vishwakarma community belong?

Tags: caste-system, smriti, manu-smriti, varna

I belong to the [Vishwakarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishwakarma_(caste)) community and am not able to decide on the caste (Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaishya or Shudra) I belong.

As per my knowledge and learning, even the Vedas, Manusmriti and other granthas are not unanimous on this.

Is there any authentic verdict on this issue?

Comment: what occupation did your paternal and maternal grandfather do ?

Answer (score 1):

About Vishvakarma being a brahmin by caste and community , I have come across authentic granth 'Bhagwadpuran'  " Shri Bhagwat -Sudha- Sagar{Shuk-Sagar} " Shrimadbhagavat Maha Puran in hindi. Published by Geeta Press Gorakhpur.
In this context kindly go through :
1.Shasth skandh - saatwaan Adhyay(page 346) to terehwaanadhyay(page 362).
After having gone through ,I feel ,there is left no doubt about Wishvkrma being a brahmin.Wishvroop and Vritrasur in the text are of Vishvakarma community and family.